# combining properties from two objects in the same array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

If  I have

```
category_hours = {
   Class: [
              {
                  hour:2,
                  minute:2
              },{
                  hour:1,
                  minute:1
              }
          ]
}
```

How can add the hours and minute together, so that I have 3 hours and 3 minutes?

I attempted this jquery.each loop but it only output each individual hour and minute, and it didnt seem to apply any of the math.

```
jQuery.each(category_hours.Class, function() 
{
    var totalHours = 0;
    var totalMins = 0;

    totalHours += parseInt(this.hour) * 60
    totalMins += parseInt(this.minute)

    var totalTime = totalHours + totalMins;
    var realMin = totalTime % 60;
    var realHour = Math.floor(totalTime / 60); 

    $('#classHr').append(realHour);
    $('#classMin').append(realMin);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `totalHours` and `totalMins` outside of the each function.

```
var totalHours = 0;
var totalMins = 0;

jQuery.each(category_hours.Class, function() 
{
    totalHours += parseInt(this.hour) * 60;
    totalMins += parseInt(this.minute);
})

var totalTime = totalHours + totalMins;
var realMin = totalTime % 60;
var realHour = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
$('#classHr').append(realHour);
$('#classMin').append(realMin);
```

Comment: This only added the hours together, but without the math needed to calculate time.

Example: I input three objects with 1 hour each.  It displayed 1,2,3 in the hour field. instead of just 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is the posterchild of what [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is meant for.

```
var o = category_hours.Class.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
  return {
    hour: previousValue.hour + currentValue.hour,
    minute: previousValue.minute + currentValue.minute
  };
});
```

After you've done this, you can easily modulo the minutes to get the final data you're after.

```
o.hour += ~~(o.minute / 60);
o.minute = o.minute % 60;
```